# NEST 5.x Fields Usage

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have two snippets of code from nest 2.3 that I haven't been able to get to cooperate in the latest 5.0.0-rc3.

```
var titleField = Infer.Field<Page>(p => p.Title, 2);
        var metaDescriptionField = Infer.Field<Page>(p => p.MetaDescription, 1.5);
        var metaKeywordsField = Infer.Field<Page>(p => p.Keywords, 2);
        var bodyField = Infer.Field<Page>(p => p.Body);

        MultiMatchQuery multiMatchQuery = new MultiMatchQuery()
        {
            Fields = new [] {
                bodyField, 
                metaKeywordsField,
                metaKeywordsField,
                titleField
            },
            Query = search.Term
        };
```

The build error here is "Cannot implicitly convert Nest.Field[] to Nest.Fields". I can do something like

```
MultiMatchQuery multiMatchQuery = new MultiMatchQuery()
        {
            Fields = Infer.Fields<Page>(p => p.Title, p => p.MetaDescription, p => p.Keywords, p => p.Body),
            Query = search.Term
        };
```

But then I lose the field weighting.

Second field useagle I've been having troubles with is

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Page>(s => s
            .MatchAll()
            .From(from)
            .Size(size)
            .Fields(f => f.Field(fi => fi.Id).Field(fi => fi.SourceId))
            );
```

Build error here is 'Nest.SearchDescriptor' does not contain a definition for 'Fields' and no extension method 'Fields' accepting a first argument of type 'Nest.SearchDescriptor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I haven't had any luck with getting something compile-able in the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit operator that converts `Field[]` to `Fields` is missing in 5.x in the latest release; I will add this in addition to other helpful overloads, to go into the next release. In the meantime, you can construct a `Fields` from fields with strong typing and boosting using

```
Fields fields = ((Fields)Infer.Field<Document>(f => f.Property1, 1.2))
                    .And<Document>(f => f.Property2, 2)
                    .And<Document>(f => f.Property3, 5);
```

You can also use strings too

```
Fields fields = new[]
{
    "property1^1.2",
    "property2^2",
    "property3^5"
};
```

For the second part, `.Fields()` on `SearchRequest` is now `.StoredFields()`, [in line with the change in Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18943), to indicate that it is to be used to retrieve stored fields only ([those set to `store:true` in the mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html)). As noted in the issue, if you were using `.Fields()` to retrieve a partial document from the `_source` field, it is recommended that you use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/source-filtering-usage.html) for this.